# springboot thymeleaf could not find static files

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I use springboot + thymeleaf, it can find the template pages, but could not find the static (css or js).

[image]

application.yml :

```
spring:
  application:
    name: exe-springboot
  thymeleaf:
    suffix: .html
  resources:
    static-locations: /static/**
```

and the controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
public String index() {
    return "index";
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/index.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h2>test page</h2>
<span class="test-span">hello world with css</span>
</body>
</html>
```

index.css

```
.test-span{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```

and browser: http://localhost:8080/index
the except color of `hello world with css` should be red, but not. and the console, with chrome, shows 404 `http://localhost:8080/static/index.css`

Comment: Can you try `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/static/index.css}" />` in your `index.html` page?

Comment: I did it as `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{index.css}"/>` ,it not work, and did as `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../static/index.css}"/>`, still not work, and the console shows 404 `http://localhost:8080/static/index.css` by the second way.

Comment: Just http://localhost:8080/index.css. Do not add 'static' does it also gives 404 ?

Comment: not 404, but still not work

Comment: When you view your source code of the page in the browser and click on the  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"/> and if you get a page with the source of the file index.css ( '.test-span{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}' ) then it is loaded  and the problem is elsewhere ?? Security maybe or somethnig if you have ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the resources in your static directory like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{index.css}"/>
```

When you are using thymeleaf do not forget "th:" and also you do not have to write the whole path to the resource you want. Spring is looking at static directory so you can access the index.css like in my example.

Also a good practise maybe is to put your css, js, fonts and images in to different folders in your static directory. For example create a folder CSS and put the index.css in it and access it in your HTML like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/index.css}"/>
```

EDIT:

Now the problems is not in the loading of the resources from your static folder. As you can see you are getting a status code 200 that means that the index.css is loaded to your HTML.

So I can suggest you better replace your  tag with :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Comment: I did it `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{index.css}"/>`, still not work.

Comment: Can you try like : `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/index.css}"/>` with the '/'. Also in your browser type :  localhost:8080/index.css and does also gives you 404 ?

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/index.css}"/>` no 404, but still not work, see my ans as the following